# terra package returns error when try to run parallel operations

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-future, terra

I'm working with `raster` package and I try to switch to `terra` but for some reasons that I don't understand, `terra` cannot reproduce the same operation of `raster` when working in parallel with packages such `snowfall` and `future.apply`. Here is a reproducible example.

```
library(terra)
r <- rast()
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
m <- rast()
m[] <- c(rep(1,ncell(m)/5),rep(2,ncell(m)/5),rep(3,ncell(m)/5),rep(4,ncell(m)/5),rep(5,ncell(m)/5))
ms <- separate(m,other=NA)
plot(ms)
mymask <- function(ind){
  tipo <- tipo_tav[ind]
  mask <- ms[[ind]]
  
  masked <-
    terra::mask(
      r,
      mask
    )
  
  richard <- function(x){
    k <-0.2
    v <-0.3
    a <-200
    y0 <-2
    y <- k/v*x*(1-((x/a)^v))+y0
    return(y)
  }
  pred <- richard(masked)
  pred <- clamp(pred,lower=0)
  return(pred)
}
#the sequential usage works fine, faster than the `raster` counterpart
system.time(x <- mymask(1))#0.03

#when I try to run my function in parallel I receive an error
plan(multisession,workers=5)
system.time(pred_list <- future_lapply(1:5, FUN = mymask))
```

> Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: (nil)>,  :
> NULL value as symbol address.

the exactly same code works well if I change `rast` with `raster` and `terra::mask` with `raster::mask`. See below:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(r)
ms <- stack(ms)
mymask <- function(ind){
  tipo <- tipo_tav[ind]
  mask <- ms[[ind]]
  
  masked <-
    raster::mask(
      r,
      mask     
    )
  
  richard <- function(x){
    k <-0.2
    v <-0.3
    a <-200
    y0 <-2
    y <- k/v*x*(1-((x/a)^v))+y0
    return(y)
  }
  pred <- richard(masked)
  pred <- clamp(pred,lower=0)
  return(pred)
}
#this works fine
system.time(x <- mymask(1))#0.06
#this works too
plan(multisession,workers=5)
system.time(pred_list <- future_lapply(1:5, FUN = mymask))#15.48
```

The same behavior if I use `snowfall` instead of `future`

```
library(snowfall)
sfInit(parallel = TRUE, cpus =5)
sfLibrary(terra)
sfExportAll()
system.time(pred_list <- sfLapply(1:5, fun = mymask))
sfStop()
```

this return the same error of `future_lapply`
Why is this happening? I've never seen such an error. I was hoping to take advantage of the higher speed of `terra` but so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A `SpatRaster` cannot be serialized, you cannot send it to parallel compute nodes. Have a look [here](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/36) for more discussion.

Instead you can (a) send and receive filenames; (b) parallelize your custom function that you supply to `app` or `lapp`; (c) use the `cores=n` argument (where available, e.g. `app` and `predict`); (d) use a mechanism like `wrap`; (e) send a filename and a vector to make a SpatExtent to process and create a virtual raster from the output tiles (see ?vrt).

For example, you could do use a function like this (Option "a")

```
prich <- function(filein, fileout) {
    r <- rast(filein)
    richard <- function(x) {
        k <-0.2
        v <-0.3
        a <-200
        y0 <-2
        y <- k/v*x*(1-((x/a)^v))+y0
        y[y<0] <- 0
        return(y)
    }
    x <- app(masked, richard, filename=fileout, overwrite=TRUE)
    return(TRUE)
}
```

I use `app` because it is much more efficient for large rasters --- as it could avoid writing temp files for each of the 10 arithmetic operations with a SpatRaster. Given that you want to parallelize this relatively simple function,  I assume the files are very large.

Or option "c":

```
richard <- function(x) {
    k <-0.2
    v <-0.3
    a <-200
    y0 <-2
    y <- k/v*x*(1-((x/a)^v))+y0
    y[y<0] <- 0
    return(y)
 }
 x <- app(masked, richard, cores=12)
```

In neither case I included the masking. You could include it in option "a" but `mask` is disk I/O intensive, not computationally intensive, so it might be as efficient to do it in one step rather than in parallel.

With `wrap` you could do something like this

```
f <- function(w) {
    x <- rast(w)
    y <- richard(x)
    wrap(y)
}

r <- rast(nrow=10, ncol=10, vals=1:100)
x <- f(wrap(r))
x <- rast(x)
```

Where `f` would be run in parallel. That only works for small rasters, but you could parallelize over tiles, and you can create tiles with `terra::makeTiles`.

More internal parallelization options will be coming, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: Thanks! option d is what i was looking for. It was not clear in either terra::wrap or in documentation of future.