# Terra R - Speed up aggregate() of raster data with custom function

Tags: r, r-raster, terra

I would like to use `aggregate` function from the `terra` `R` package to aggregate raster with a quantiles approach as aggregation function. Here below, I used the `quantile` function from `R base` to compute 50th percentile (i.e. the median) using a raster from the local package directory. I chose the 50th percentile for comparison with median but my goal is indeed to compute other quantile(s)...

```
library(terra)
# load elevation coming with the terra pakage
r <- rast( system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") )

plot(r)

# number of iteration
n_it <- 20

# with a custom function
start_time <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:n_it){
ra <- aggregate(r, 2 , fun = function(x) quantile(x, probs = .5, na.rm = T))
}
end_time <- Sys.time()
```

It took my computer approx. 6 secs to do it 20 times.

```
print(end_time-start_time)
```

> Time difference of 6.052727 secs

WHen I ran the same `aggregate` run with the median built-in function, it took approx. 40 times less time to perform the very same 20 iterations!

```
# with a built-in function
start_time <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:n_it){
  ra <- aggregate(r, 2 , fun = median)
}
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

> Time difference of 0.1456101 secs

As I would like to compute other percentiles than the 50th, could someone provide some advises to speed up `aggregate` when using custom functions?

Comment: Google `"r fast quantile function"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the replies, I tested two options: the use of [`tdigest` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=tdigest) and the built-in parallelization routine from `terra` package (`cores` parameter). The t-Digest construction algorithm, by [Dunning et al., (2019)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.04023v1), uses a variant of 1-dimensional k-means clustering to produce a very compact data structure that allows accurate estimation of quantiles. I recommend to use the `tquantile` function, which reduced by third the processing time with the tested dataset.

For those who were thinking about `foreach` parallelization, there are no simple solution to run foreach loop with terra objects. For such tasks, I'm still using the good old raster package. [It is a planned update but not on short term - see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445883/terra-package-returns-error-when-try-to-run-parallel-operations). More details below.

## Toy dataset

```
library(terra)
# load elevation coming with the terra pakage
r <- rast( system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra") )

plot(r)

# number of iteration
n_it <- 20

# With `stats::quantile()` function
start_time <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:n_it){
  ra <- aggregate(r, 2 , fun = function(x) quantile(x, probs = .5, na.rm = T))
}
end_time <- Sys.time()
print(end_time-start_time)
```

> Time difference of 6.013551 secs

## With `tdigest::tquantile()`

```
library(tdigest)

start_time_tdigest <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:n_it){
  ra_tdigest <- aggregate(r, 2 , fun = function(x) tquantile(tdigest(na.omit(x)), probs = .5))
  }
end_time_tdigest <- Sys.time()
print(end_time_tdigest-start_time_tdigest)
```

> Time difference of 1.922526 secs

As suspected by Martin, the use of the `cores` parameter in the `terra:aggregate` function did not improve the processing time:

## `stats::quantile()` + parallelization

```
start_time_parallel <- Sys.time() 
for (i in 1:n_it){
ra_tdigest_parallel <- aggregate(r, 2 , fun = function(x) quantile(x, probs = .5, na.rm = T), cores = 2) 
} 
end_time_parallel <- Sys.time() 
print(end_time_parallel-start_time_parallel)
```

> Time difference of 8.537751 secs

## `tdigest::tquantile()` + parallelization

```
tdigest_quantil_terra <- function(x) {   
require(tdigest)   
tquantile(tdigest(na.omit(x)), probs = .5) }
        
start_time_tdigest_parallel <- Sys.time() for (i in 1:n_it){
ra_tdigest_parallel <- aggregate(r, 2 , 
fun = function(x, ff) ff(x), cores = 2 , 
ff = tdigest_quantil_terra)     
} 

end_time_tdigest_parallel <- Sys.time() 
print(end_time_tdigest_parallel-start_time_tdigest_parallel)
```

> Time difference of 7.520231 secs

In a nutshell:

> 1                tdigest 1.922526 secs
>
> 2          base_quantile 6.013551 secs
>
> 3       tdigest_parallel 7.520231 secs
>
> 4 base_quantile_parallel 8.537751 secs

Answer (score 4):

It is not that `aggregate()` is slow per se when using custom functions. Rather it is more expensive to use `quantile()` instead of `median()` to obtain the median. This is presumably due to the cost of the computation itself (terra uses a [C++ implementation to compute the median](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/331cdf5323d5a67cc03e04cfa5aa27d88a06d4d0/src/math_utils.cpp) that is faster than for an [arbitrary quantile](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/da306bd082d5773d7f52c7871fbf32269f4560bc/src/raster_stats.cpp)) and also because `quantile()` performs more checks and thus calls more additional functions in the process. This higher computational cost adds up when the operation is performed multiple times as done by `aggregate`.

If you have a much larger raster it could be beneficial to distribute computations across multiple cores using the `cores` argument, see `?terra::aggregate`. However, I think this is not an option for the `elev` data as the overhead is too large.

If you want to call `aggregate` for many different `probs` you could parallelize the loop, e.g. using the [*foreach* package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.html).

Comment: Thanks. I think that foreach loop are not really an option with terra. Or at least, it is far less complicated to do it with raster package. See more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445883/terra-package-returns-error-when-try-to-run-parallel-operations

Comment: After some time, there is a rather simple solution: load the terra object within the foreach loop. This is not efficient in terms of RAM handling but actually working