# Parallelizing terra::crop

Tags: r, raster, terra

I'm trying to parallelize `terra::crop` but I get the error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "NULL value passed as symbol address"

I know SpatRast can't be serialized but in the Github issue section I've found some solutions involving `wrap`ing the raster, or passing the filename instead of the `rast` object. However none of this solution works for me:

```
library(terra)
j <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
v <- vect(j)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
w <- wrap(r)

cl <- makeCluster(6)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#passing a wrapped SpatRast
cropped <- foreach(i=1:6,.packages = "terra")%dopar%{
  reg <- v[i]
  crp <- terra::crop(w,reg,mask=T)
  return(crp)
}

#reading the raster in the nodes
cropped <- foreach(i=1:6,.packages = "terra")%dopar%{
      r <- rast(f)
      reg <- v[i]
      crp <- terra::crop(w,reg,mask=T)
      return(crp)
    }

#and also doing all inside the loop does not works
cropped <- foreach(i=1:6,.packages = "terra")%dopar%{
  r <- rast(f)
  w <- wrap(r)
  reg <- v[i]
  crp <- terra::crop(w,reg,mask=T)
  return(crp)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

in the last example I get another error:

> Error in { : task 1 failed - "external pointer is not valid"

Can someone guide me through this problem?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445883/terra-package-returns-error-when-try-to-run-parallel-operations/67449818#67449818 and the associated thread https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/36

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of this question because I did it! I have post another question because in the answer and issue you linked I have not found a working solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(terra)
library(doParallel)
j <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")

cl <- makeCluster(6)
registerDoParallel(cl)

cropped <- foreach(i=1:6,
                   .packages = "terra") %dopar% {
  reg <-  vect(j)[i]
  crp <- wrap(terra::crop(rast(f),
                          reg,
                          mask=T))
  return(crp)
}

lapply(cropped,unwrap)
```