# Multiply a single band raster by a vector in parallel in R terra

Tags: r, parallel-processing, raster, terra

I would like to perform the following vector*raster multiplication in parallel, since my vector is very long:

```
library(terra)

# Create a raster example

set.seed(123)

raster_example <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, vals = rnorm(100))

# Create a vector example
vector_ejemplo <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)

# Perform multiplication 
result_no_parallel <- vector_ejemplo * raster_example


print(result_no_parallel)
```

I tried with `terra::app`, but I am getting errors only.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please have a look on parallelization example in thread: https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/36

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rast` object cannot be serialized (have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67445883/terra-package-returns-error-when-try-to-run-parallel-operations) and related links). But you can send names or paths to nodes, or you can `wrap` your raster to send it to nodes. Here is a toy example with your data. Note that this example has no time gain since the overheads of having multiple nodes are more significant than the speed gain. Since multiplication is a C++ function in `terra` optimized for speed and memory usage, I imagine your raster is enormous if you need to parallelize such a simple operation.

```
library(terra)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
# Create a raster example

set.seed(123)

raster_example <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, vals = rnorm(100))
path <-file.path(tempdir(),"ejemplo.tif")
writeRaster(raster_example,path)

# Create a vector example
vector_ejemplo <- c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)



f <- function(path,n) {
  x <- rast(path)
  y <- x*n
  wrap(y)
}

cl <- makeCluster(10)
registerDoParallel(cl)

result <- foreach(n=vector_ejemplo,.packages="terra")%dopar%{
  f(path,n)
}

stopCluster(cl)
x <- do.call(c,lapply(result, unwrap))
```

See `?wrap` for more details on this beautiful function that makes parallelization with `rast` objects possible.