Error in parallel computing with SpatRaster objects (terra package) in R
I'm trying to apply a function using parallel computing. The function modifies projections, crops rasters, and fills gaps in the rasters. The majority of my variables are of type SpatRaster (terra package in R). I'm using parallel computing because the function needs to be applied to a very large quantity of rasters. When I run the function sequentially with a "for loop", the script works. However, when I use parallel computing, I get this error message:
<simpleError in .External(structure(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid",     address = <pointer: (nil)>, dll = structure(list(name = "Rcpp",         path = "C:/Users/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.3/Rcpp/libs/x64/Rcpp.dll",         dynamicLookup = TRUE, handle = <pointer: (nil)>, info = <pointer: (nil)>), class = "DLLInfo"),     numParameters = -1L), class = c("ExternalRoutine", "NativeSymbolInfo")), <pointer: (nil)>, <pointer: (nil)>, .pointer): NULL value passed as symbol address>

The problem seems to arise from the fact that terra objects are non-exportable according to this post. However, I'm not sure if there is a solution to this problem. I have a large quantity of rasters (N = 50), and the execution time of the function for one raster is approximately 18 minutes. Also, I don't see any other solutions besides parallel computing. So, any help would be greatly appreciated. My script is a bit complex, but I've pinpointed the moment when I get the error message. Here's a reproducible example.
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(doSNOW)
library(tidyterra)
library(raster)

year <- as.character(seq(2010, 2011, 1))
continent_map <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(continent = "North America", returnclass = "sf")

## Build the rasters
density_r <- terra::rast(nrows = 9170, ncols = 19150, xmin = -171.7929, xmax = -12.20958, ymin = 7.224584, ymax = 83.64125, resolution = 0.008333333, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs")
terra::values(density_r) <- 1:terra::ncell(density_r)
density_r <- terra::rast(replicate(length(year), density_r))
names(density_r) <- paste0("year_", year)

climate_r <- terra::rast(nrows = 258, ncols = 599, xmin = -171.75, xmax = -22, ymin = 12, ymax = 76.5, resolution = 0.25, crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs")
terra::values(climate_r) <- 1:terra::ncell(climate_r)

cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2, outfile = "MakeCluster_output.txt")
doSNOW::registerDoSNOW(cl)

## Loop over the years
foreach_test_1 <- foreach::foreach(i = 1:2, .errorhandling = "pass") %dopar% {
  
  r <- function_test(density_raster = density_r[[i]], reference_climate_raster = climate_r)
  
  return(r)
}

## Stop the parallel backend
parallel::stopCluster(cl)

## Define the function
function_test <- function(density_raster, reference_climate_raster){
  
  ## print("A")
  ## Test if the projection of boundary polygons is different from that of the density raster
  if(!terra::same.crs(density_raster, continent_map)){
    ## Change the projection of boundary polygons
    continent_map <- sf::st_transform(continent_map, terra::crs(density_raster, proj=TRUE))
  }
  
  ## print("B")
  ## Crop the density raster
  density_raster <- terra::crop(density_raster, terra::vect(continent_map))
  density_raster <- terra::mask(density_raster, terra::vect(continent_map))
  ## plot(density_raster)
  
  ## print("C")
  ## Test if the density raster and the reference climate raster do not have the same geometries
  if(class(try(!terra::compareGeom(density_raster, reference_climate_raster, res=TRUE), silent=TRUE)) %in% "try-error"){
    
    ## Resample the raster
    density_raster <- terra::project(density_raster,  reference_climate_raster, method = "bilinear")
    
  } else if(!terra::compareGeom(density_raster, reference_climate_raster, res=TRUE)){
    
    ## Resample the raster
    density_raster <- terra::project(density_raster,  reference_climate_raster, method = "bilinear")
    
  }
  return(density_raster)
}


I believe this question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449818/635245
